# which one is required to fetch openfire messages MAM XEP-0313 or XEP-0136

Tags: xmpp, chat, archive, openfire, message

I am new to OpenFire. I am working on a task to fetch openfire chat messages for date range. While googling i read in some post that it can be done using xep-0136 while other posts suggested MAM XEP-0313.

Can somebody please help me on this.Which plugin i need to install for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Openfire has XEP-0136 support for a long time, while XEP-0363 support was added recently. So now you can use both protocols